# strip non-numeric values is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want all non-numeric characters to be removed from a `div`

for example:

```
<div class="publication_date> c2011. </div>
```

should appear

```
<div class="publication_date> 2011 </div>
```

I tried

```
$(".publication_date").html($(".publication_date").html().replace(/[^0-9]+/g, ''));
```

and it is giving all dates as `2000`

Comment: You mean it changes `c2011` into `2000`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `.each()`:

```
$('.publication_date').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\D+/g, ''));
});
```

The `.html()` function, when passed no arguments, returns the value for the **first** element matched by the initial selector.  If your first element had been "c2009.", then all of your other elements would have been "2009" instead of "2000".

By using `.each()`, you handle each "publication_date" element individually.

Also I modified the regex a little; `\D` means "not a digit".